# Unity inventory system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the difference between I Formatter and JSON for inventory system in unity c#? Currently I am using binary formatter with JSON utility to store data in a database to save and load the data.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to use JSON for unity because the binary formatter is inconsistent with file reading when adding new objects, variables etc or so I have heard

Comment: can you share the source please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide

Comment: @Armin not only inconsistent ... the docs literally state `The BinaryFormatter type is dangerous and is not recommended for data processing. Applications should stop using BinaryFormatter as soon as possible, even if they believe the data they're processing to be trustworthy. BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, binaryformatter can be considered outdated and should not be used if your game needs even the most basic security.

Json is a great alternative, I would personally recommend Newtonsoft as it solves most problems JSON had like handling dictionaries and etc.

Found at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Also there is some great extensions available [here](https://github.com/NServiceBusExtensions/Newtonsoft.Json.Encryption)

> Leverages the Newtonsoft extension API to encrypt/decrypt specific nodes at serialization time. So only the nodes that require encryption are touched, the remaining content is still human readable. This approach provides an compromise between readability/debugabaility and security.

Though you might need to get proper licensing on the encryption.